# App icons don't appear in system tray on Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

Today I've noticed that system tray doesn't show application icons, for example, Viber, Skype, Software update.

I've tried:

- to reboot
- to reinstall Skype
- to run Skype and Viber from command line hoping I would see an error (something like permission problem)
- to create a new user and check with it - application icons **do appear** then in new user session

I don't know what else to check.

Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa 64-bit (Cinnamon).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was found that "System tray" applet was disabled in my system.

Fixed in this way:

- enter app menu
- type "Applets" and press "Enter" button
- on "Installed Applets" tab search for "System tray" applet
- select it and press "Add to panel" button
- some running applications might need to be restarted in order to appear in the tray

Comment: Is for when you have not added the System Tray Applet? Because I have a similar issue in which the Applet has been added but those specific icons do not appear.

Comment: Same here. I accidentally clicked 'remove from system tray', but I don't know how to add it back!